# Perl Regular Expression Pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I have some data as such :

```
TYPE: Travel
ADDRESS
  Barcelona
  Paris
```

So, address can be 1 or many (I need to discard ADDRESS and get only those cities). For some reason my parsing fails (only "ADDRESS" is printed) to produce the correct result.Am i missing something ?

```
elsif (/^ADDRESS/) {
    my @address_t = split /[no matter what i put,only ADDRESS is printed]+/, $_;
        shift @address_t;  #is this how i will discard ADDRESS ?

        foreach my $address (@address_t) {
                @address_names = ($address);            
    }
```

I think the regex is suppose to be split a newline, space ?

This is how i processed TYPE:

```
elsif (/^TYPE/) {
            my @type_t = split '\s', $_;
            $type = $type_tmp[1];
                    print "$type" ; #to test, but i have a hashmap which i load them in and print at the end of the file.
```

Thanks

Comment: is there a loop around the if/elsif? Do you have all the data in memory or just one line?

Comment: I have a print statement inside the foreach loop which i used to testing just ommited in this post. Normally i load the data in a hash. But i haven't gotten there yet since the simple print statement doesn't give me what i want. The loop gives ADDRESS(for as many times as it is in the text file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while(<DATA>) {
    if (/^ADDRESS/) {           # if line contains ADDRESS then read addresses
        while (<DATA>) {        # ... in a loop
            last if !/^ +/;     # until we find a non-indented line
            print $_;           # here you can push $_ to a list
        }
    }   
    if ($_ && /^TYPE/) {        # a TYPE after address can be processed now
        # stuff 
    }   
}

__DATA__
TYPE: Travel
ADDRESS
  Barcelona
  Paris
TYPE: Travel
ADDRESS
  Barcelona
  Paris
```

*Produces:*

```
  Barcelona
  Paris
  Barcelona
  Paris
```

Comment: thank you for your reply and time. Is there any way in which you could answer based on what i already have as code ? There is a style i am using that using yours will get me confused since i am new to perl and programming. Btw, there are other attributes above "TYPE" i just gave a small view of the DataSet.I will show you how i processed Type. I just edited the question and added.

Comment: You can't split ADDRESS line, that line only contains one word. Try to understand the code I have above. If no other attribute except ADDRESS  span over multiple lines you can just attach them as elsif statements to the TYPE block.

Comment: ADDRESS is the last of a record(TYPE AND ADDRESS were just the two last records which i decided to show here). Every next new record starts after a white space with "TIME" that follows.i processed "TIME" and other attributes already. It's just this ADDRESS that i can't get the regex to get the values and discard "ADDRESS" among it's results.

Comment: The order of blocks does not matter if you structure the loop carefully.

Comment: please how can i substitute, the default variable $_ to an actual variable ? I am already using $_ .

Comment: just use `$var` instead of `$_`. What are you using the `$_` for? It should be the current line from the file.

Comment: #perreal yea i did. Both worked, i still did not grasp the fundamental concepts well(y).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

It will print lines if the previous line matches `/^ADDRESS/`. Let me know if there's a point at which you want to stop, and I can adjust...

```
use warnings;
use strict; 

my $current_line = "";
my $line_count = 0;

while (<IN>){
    chomp;
    my $previous_line = $current_line;
    $current_line = $_;
    if ($previous_line =~ /^ADDRESS/ or $line_count > 0 ){
    $line_count++;
    print "$current_line\n"

    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am afraid i will like to stick with the format i used. you can take a look at the way i processed TYPE for example.ADDRESS is the last of the record. The new record starts after a white space.